# How can I center a vertical list?

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I can't center the text inside a vertical list. The trouble is when one line items are centered, two line items get decentralized.

The code is:

```
/*This is the one which works with more than one line links*/
 .enlaces .enlacePortada a{
    display: block;
    padding: 0em 0.1em;
    margin:auto;    
}


/*The following works with single line links: */ 
.enlaces .enlacePortada a{
    display: block;
    padding: 0em 0.1em;
        margin-top: 0.2em; 
    margin: 0.4em auto 0.3em auto;
}
```

I also tried:

```
vertical-align: middle;
text-align: center;
align-content: center;
```

and there is not any change.

Here is a **minimalist sample: http://jsfiddle.net/uZmQL/**

Comment: Please provide a working sample. For example: go to http://jsfiddle.net/ and fill in some HTML and CSS, press `Run` to see that it is working as you expect it, and then press `Save` and share the URL in your question.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. 

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/uZmQL/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem, you have a simple HTML list and you want to center text ?

Is that you wanted to do ?

```
li {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 2px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L9R7n/1/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correct then `vertical-align: middle;` is the way to go, but `vertical-align` only applies to the line height so it wont work for a block element.

So what you have to do is to make your LI´s to `inline-block` elements and then apply the `vertical-align: middle` to them.

[Example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B8ev5/)

This is not a 100% pulletprofe solution but it will work in most moden browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding a class to single line links.

CSS:

```
.enlacesLine1 {
    line-height: 40px;
}
```

Html:

```
<div > 
    <ul > 
        <li class="titulo"> SERVICES</li>
        <li class="enlaces enlacesLine1"> 
            <a href="">Service 1</a> </li>
        <li class="enlaces enlacesLine1"> 
            <a href="">Service 2</a></li>
        <li class="enlaces"> 
            <a href="">Service 3-1 <br/> Service 3-2</a></li>
    </ul> 
</div>
```

You can check the whole example in: http://jsfiddle.net/uZmQL/2/